# SQL CASE Statement Change the Column name in THEN clause

Tags: sql

I'm beginner in SQL,is it possible to change column name in CASE statement.
I've a column name as "Inbound" the value for it can be '1' or '2'. If it's 1 the column name should be AS "IN" ELSE "OUT".

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Column names are defined at prepare time, before any table data is known.

Comment: You can not generate dynamic column names. Queries should be static.

Comment: Ok, thank you @jarlh

Comment: Ok, thank you @juergend.

Comment: You can't do that, as this would mean that the column could have a different name for each row - which isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can not generate dynamic column names. Queries should be static. But what you could do is for instance:

```
select case when inbound = 1 then 'yes' end as in_result,
       case when inbound = 2 then 'yes' end as out_result
from your_table
```

Comment: I tried the above query, it's very close to requirement, but the only thing is it adds new column "out_result". Thank you very much @juergend.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this instead:

```
select
  case
    when inbound = 1 then 'yes' as in_result
    when inbound = 2 then 'yes'
  end as out_result
from your_table
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a syntax error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't have a column name be dynamic. Your best bet is:

```
select
  case
    when inbound = 1 then 'in'
    when inbound = 2 then 'out'
  end as result
from your_table
```